# unable to execute dex : multiple dex files define Landroid

Tags: android, android-appcompat

i had these issues when i tried to running my apps and have no idea how to fix it ...

anyone please help me out

this is the errors :

```
[2014-04-18 18:47:35 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
[2014-04-18 18:47:35 - CQUdiary] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you add v7 appcompat support library externally,please unchecked your android dependencies from order and export section and remove android dependencies from libraries section.
this is how I fixed it:
right click on the project->select java build path->go to order and export section -> unchecked android dependencies and remove android dependencies from Libraries section ->
clean -> rebuild

Comment: Great! You saved other waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you more than one java files with same name. therefore it tries to convert .class to de files it gave this error.

Check that whether this is happening or not

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one copy of the v7 appcompat support library (android-support-v7-appcompat.jar) in your project. Remove the duplicates and rebuild.

Comment: i dont have any duplicate of that ... how do u know if i have 2 v7 appcompat ?

Comment: From the class name `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$Callback`. Alphabetically it's the first class in the v7 support jar so if you have that jar twice, you get this error.

Comment: but apparently there are no items that are duplicate , i mean for the jar @laalto